# Ember deploy error: Unable to sync: UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `(my-asset-bucket-name)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ember.js, deployment, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to deploy an ember cli app using ember-cli-deploy(v 0.4), ember-deploy-s3, and ember-deploy-s3-index... very much in the same way as beautifully described here: http://kerrygallagher.co.uk/deploying-an-ember-cli-application-to-amazon-s3/ .

I was able to deploy the app several time and was also able to navigate to it in the browser. Because of a different problem that I had involving the `gzip: true` flag in my config/deploy file, I manually deleted all the files in both my asset and index buckets on s3. After removing the files, I'm now unable to deploy at all and faced with this error:

```
Unable to sync: UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `(MY-ASSET-BUCKET-NAME).s3.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1' region.
    at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (node_modules/ember-deploy-s3/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:355:46)
    at Request.callListeners (/node_modules/ember-deploy-s3/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:100:18)
    at Request.emit (/node_modules/ember-deploy-s3/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/node_modules/ember-deploy-s3/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:604:14)
    at ClientRequest.error (/node_modules/ember-deploy-s3/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:204:22)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/node_modules/ember-deploy-s3/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:61:19)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1552:9)
    at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.onerror (tls.js:1456:17)
```

I've tried many things from deleting and re-creating my s3 buckets to reinstalling ember-cli-deploy, ember-deploy-s3, and ember-deploy-s3-index.

My best guess at this point is that ember is for some reason attempting to sync or find the old deleted revisions and then the error gets thrown? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Here's some more information about my overall configuration:

config/deploy.js

```
staging: {
    store: {
      type: 'S3',      
      accessKeyId: 'XXXXX',
      secretAccessKey: 'XXXXX',
      bucket: 'MY-BUCKET-NAME',
      indexMode: 'indirect'
    },
    assets: {
      type: 's3',
      accessKeyId: 'XXXXX',
      secretAccessKey: 'XXXXX',
      bucket: 'MY-ASSET-BUCKET-NAME'
    },
    // manifestPrefix: 'ember-admin-staging' // optional, defaults to this.project.name()
  },
```

Fingerprinting (from ember-cli-builds.js) :

```
fingerprint: {
      // enabled: enableFingerprint,
      enabled: true,
      prepend: 'MY-ASSET-BUCKET',
}
```

I chose the standard-us region for both buckets.

These issues are happening for the 'staging environment', and I'm attempting to deploy with this command: `ember deploy --environment staging`

Finally, some files are actually being uploaded to my assets bucket, but no files are put into the bucket that used to contain my index file.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: So, I was actually able to remedy the problem, but I decided to leave this open because I have no idea why it suddenly works. I was trying to debug by seeing how the node packages actually interact with each other (and trying to discover where it was breaking, or get more information about the error). I got as far as node_modules/s3/lib/index where I put a console.log inside the syncDir function (line 888). I deployed again, but the deployment just hung (after logging the text). I removed the console log and deployed again, and suddenly, a successful deploy! But why??!

Comment: I just ran into the same issue, and changed nothing, and it worked again. For me, I think it was just my internet connectivity not working for a moment.